# Cannot find module 'newman' Require stack:

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, newman

I installed "newman" package on my computer globally and **able to run newman on the command line**

```js
npm install -g newman
```

However, I need to run my test collections in nodejs script and the following statement throws an exception

***Cannot find module 'newman' Require stack:***

```js
const newman = require('newman');
```

Any ideas to fix this problem?

Austin

```
// this is full error stack
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'newman'
Require stack:
- C:\xxx\postman-tests\parallel.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xxx\postman-tests\parallel.js:8:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\xxx\\postman-tests\\parallel.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you post the full error?

Comment: Just updated the question with full error stack

Comment: You would need to create a `package.json` file and save Newman as one of the dependencies before running the script

Comment: This works, I was confused about the global package. I need to install it locally too.

Answer (score 7):

you have installed `newman` package globally. In order to use it in your project you need to install it locally in your project. If your project does not have a `package.json` file you can init it by running `npm init` in the root directory of your project. After that you can install the package by `npm install newman` to add it to your dependencies. Now the package can be required within your project.

Comment: What I said in the comment. You should accept this answer 

Comment: This works, I was confused about the global package. I need to install it locally too.